# Cannot find a handler for POST with boundary

Tags: java, unit-testing, http, junit

I'm in the midst of testing my application which is using an HTTP-server. Instead of mocking I decided to go with a HTTP server fixture. Meaning that I do not have to mock any productional code. To accomplish this goal I currently chose for a free to use 3rd party library [fixd](https://github.com/lantunes/fixd).

I was able to successfully create several unit tests - which are working by means of a GET request. Most are quite simple, i.e.:

```
@Test
public void verifyConnectionTest()
{
    try
    {
        final String body = FileUtils.readFileToString(RESOURCE);
        final String path = "/";

        this.server.handle(Method.GET, path).with(
                new HttpRequestHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(final HttpRequest request,
                            final HttpResponse response)
                    {
                        response.setStatusCode(200);
                        response.setContentType("text/xml");
                        response.setBody(body);
                    }
                });

        // Setting up my HTTP client
        // Execute some tasks
        // asserting of everything was valid
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But I now have to send a POST request with multipart/form-data. Which does not make much of a difference other than changing the method and content-type:

```
@Test
public void executeStepTest()
{
    try
    {
        final String body = FileUtils.readFileToString(SERVICE_RESPONSE);
        final String path = "/";

        this.server.handle(Method.POST, path, "multipart/form-data").with(
                new HttpRequestHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(final HttpRequest request,
                            final HttpResponse response)
                    {
                        response.setStatusCode(200);
                        response.setContentType("text/xml");
                        response.setBody(body);
                    }
                });

                // Setting up my HTTP client
                // Execute some tasks
                // asserting of everything was valid
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

However I get the following error: `[ERROR] could not find a handler for POST - / - multipart/form-data; boundary=bqCBI7t-VW1xaJW7BADmTiGMg9w_YM2sHH8ukJYx` and my guess is that fixd doesn't recognize the boundary-party. Since the documentation does not show an example I'm quite stuck on this part.

I tried using some wildcards such as '*', no succes. Thus; I need a way to either tell fixd to accept that boundary or use some wildcards I didn't yet discover. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been making some debug and it seems to be that the problem is in the `fixd` core.

Basically, `fixd` indexes every `RequestHandlerImpl` by a `HandlerKey` (which includes **ContentType** as part of the key) in the map `handlerMap`. See method `org.bigtesting.fixd.core.FixtureContainer#resolve`.

```
...
HandlerKey key = new HandlerKey(method, route, contentType);
RequestHandlerImpl handler = handlerMap.get(key);
if (handler == null) {
  // Error
}
...
```

**Problem**: When the request is `multipart/form-data`, `boundary` data (which it's generated dinamically every request) is part of the content type. So, any handler is found in `handlerMap` because the key changes with every running.

I've made a little test only to check that this is the cause of the problem, passing the contentType to fixd `server.handle` after the creation of the multipart request, and it works fine.

See the test below:

```
   @Test
   public void verifyConnectionTest_multipart() {
      try {
         // 1. Create multipart request (example with http-commons 3.1)
         PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod(url);
         Part[] parts = { new StringPart("param", "value") };
         MultipartRequestEntity request = new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, filePost.getParams());
         filePost.setRequestEntity(request);

         // 2. fixd server handle (passing the request content type)
         this.server.handle(Method.POST, "/", request.getContentType()).with(
               new HttpRequestHandler() {

                  @Override
                  public void handle(final HttpRequest request,
                                     final HttpResponse response) {
                     response.setStatusCode(200);
                     response.setContentType("text/xml");
                  }
               });

         // 3. Execute multipart request
         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
         int status = client.executeMethod(filePost);

         // 4. Assertions
         Assert.assertEquals(200, status);

      } catch (Exception e) {
         Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
```

Hope it helps you to clarify the problem. Cheers

Comment: Perfect catch! I was searching in the right direction, but unable to solve it. The system is now pushing out a HttpPost-object (org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost). From this point I can retrieve the content type - and if I want the (correct) path. Pass it to fixd and done - I have a handle. Thanks once more!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in `fixd`, and has been fixed in version 1.0.3. Your original code should work using this new version of `fixd`.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Comment: I tried to post a comment initially, but I wasn't allowed to. I saw a message saying I must have 50 reputation to comment.